# Make the FlipView scroll smoother

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, scroll

I am programming a Windows 8.1 App using C#/XAML as well as the MVVM-Light Toolkit.

In that App I have a FlipView with an items in it that occupy the space of the whole Page. However when scrolling between them it does not look smooth because instead of really scrolling the FlipView directly displays about 8/10 on one side of the item that is being scrolled to and then just scrolls the left 20%.

My question now is whether it is possible to make the FlipView display all of the content. I've also thought about replacing the FlipView with a GridView. That would imply the problem of switching directly to the next item when the GridView is scrolled.

I don't see any code in my App that fits the question and research did not provide an answer yet.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I just had an unnecessary, complex task running every time the user scrolls. The issue I had was just a lag. Since it was the first time I used a FlipView I thought that was regular behaviour haha :D

Thank you anyways :)